# Problem optimizing data under conditional python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dataframe

I have created a code which extracts certain values based on the data **'input_data [i] [2] and input_data [i] [3]'** from an Excel database to store them in a **'base'** list to said data later I relate them to obtain an **'R'** value.

```
import pandas as pd 
input_data = [[1, 'Col', 'D', '21X62'],
                [2, 'Col', 'D', '12X62'],
                [3, 'Col', 'D', '21X68'],
                [4, 'Col', 'D', '21X62'],
                [5, 'Row', 'D', '12X45'],
                [6, 'Row', 'D', '12X45']]


ExcelPrincipal = pd.ExcelFile('example.xlsx')
base = []
for i in range(len(input_data)): 

    if input_data[i][2] == 'A':
        data = ExcelPrincipal.parse('A') 

    elif input_data[i][2] == 'D':
        data = ExcelPrincipal.parse('D') 

    for j in range(len(data)):
        if input_data[i][3] == data.values[j][0]:
            base.append([data.values[j][1], data.values[j][2]])     

print('Element',5*' ','Ratio')
R_list = []
for i in range(len(input_data)):
    if input_data[i][1] == 'Col':
        R = round(base[i][1]/base[i][0],3) 
        R_list.append(R)

        print(f"{i+1:02} {R:>16}")    

#while R_list[i] < 0.5:
#    
#    for j in range(len(R_list)):
#        if input_data[i][1] == 'Col':
#            R = round(base[i][1]/base[i][0],3) 
#            R_list.append(R)
```

Now I am trying to make the values of **‘R’** exceed the threshold of **0.5**, for this it is necessary to find from the **‘data’** the values that cause that threshold to be exceeded. I've thought of a While loop, which evaluates the values of **R_list**, but I think it could be better optimized. Is there a better solution in this regard?

I want that when printed it exceeds this threshold

```
Element         Ratio
01              > 0.5
02              > 0.5
03              > 0.5
04              > 0.5
```

Best regards.